# /Volumes vs /media/${name}

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

A fellow Kindle user wrote a simple script to remove adds from the eReader here: https://github.com/mariopepe/KindleAdRemover/blob/master/KindleAdRemover.sh

As you can see it's removing the .assets folder containing the ads, and creating a malformed file instead so the ads can't be pulled from it.

On my system (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64), I don't have a `/Volumes` folder containing mounted drives, but instead it's located in `/media/franfran`.

Is there a way to programatically know this, either by try-catching in the bash script, or by calling a method, and more importantly, did I changed something (probably) in the past that would have made the system mount it to a custom location ?

Thanks, and have a nice day.

Comment: To my knowledge, `/media/$USER` is the preferred automount folder in Linux, while I know `/Volumes` for all users from some BSD. So no to the last question: You didn't change the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would posit that the script was written by a Mac user, as this draws heavily from BSD and also uses `/Volumes` as a result.

Speculation aside, it should be a fairly simple edit to be more flexible to suit your use case.

```
# place this at line 2
for dir in "/Volumes" "/media/${USER}" "" ; do
  [ -d "${dir}" ] && echo "Found mount directory at ${dir}" && break
done

[ -z "${dir} ] && echo "Could not find mount directory" && exit 1
```

Change all instances of

```
/Volumes/Kindle/system/.assets
```

to be

```
${dir}/Kindle/system/.assets
```

## At your own risk, no warranty expressed or implied